# Return value from wcf async call in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I want to get the value from a wcf async call.

```
public DateTime currentDateTime;
private void GetDateTime()
    {
        var client = new WcfClient();
        client.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted -= ClientGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
        client.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted += ClientGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
        client.GetCurrentDateTimeAsync();
    }

    private void ClientGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted(object sender, GetCurrentDateTimeCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Error == null && args.Result != null)
            {
                currentDateTime = args.Result;
            }
        }
```

To call this method. I use `GetDateTime`. 
My question is the code didn't reach the method at all in the debug mode. The result time is `Date = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`.

I know I call it synchronously. But how to get it in the debug model?

Comment: It might be an issue with the call being async when you're trying to debug.   Have you been able to debug other async calls?

Comment: @Tim, I just realized that I have to hit F5 again. Then the code can be reached. But it leave the current stacktrace, I am not sure where it is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is putting a breakpoint at the first line of the async method and pressing F5, the debugger should stop there and you can debug it.

See [here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d36e03c8-114f-4cce-a336-280c59a66afe/how-to-debug-the-async-methods-?forum=csharpgeneral)

Also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155813.aspx) has the document.